# I have the problem that the state cannot be mounted correctly after updating the state by clicking buttons

Tags: reactjs

**context/cart.jsx**

```
import { useState, useContext, createContext, useEffect } from "react";

const CartContext = createContext()

const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [cart,setCart] = useState([])
    const existingCartItems = localStorage.getItem("cart")
   
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(cart){
            setCart(JSON.parse(existingCartItems))
        }
    }, [])

    // console.log(cartTotal)

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={[ cart, setCart ]}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )
}

const useCart = () => useContext(CartContext)

export { useCart, CartProvider }
```

**CartPage.jsx**

```
const [cart, setCart] = useCart()
    const [clientToken, setClientToken] = useState("")
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    console.log(cart)

    const cartTotal = cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.quantity, 0)

return (
<button className='increaseQtyBtn'
                                            onClick={() => {
                                                setCart(
                                                    cart.map((c) => {
                                                        if(c._id === p._id){
                                                            console.log(c.quantity)
                                                            return {...c, quantity: ++c.quantity}
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                )
                                                localStorage.setItem(
                                                    "cart",
                                                    JSON.stringify([...cart ])
                                                )
                                            }}>
                                                +
                                            </button>
                                            <button className='decreaseQtyBtn'
                                            onClick={() => {
                                                setCart(
                                                    cart.map((c) => {
                                                        if(c._id === p._id){
                                                            if(c.quantity === 1){
                                                                console.log(c)
                                                                cart.filter((c) => c._id !== p._id)
                                                                setCart(
                                                                    ...cart
                                                                )
                                                            } else{
                                                                return {...c, quantity: --c.quantity}
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                )
                                                localStorage.setItem(
                                                    "cart",
                                                    JSON.stringify([...cart ])
                                                )
                                            }}>-</button>
```

**Header.jsx**

```
const [auth, setAuth] = useAuth()
    const [ cart, setCart ] = useCart()
    const categories = useCategory()

    const cartTotal = cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.quantity, 0)

return (
               <Badge count={cartTotal} showZero>
                                <NavLink className="link" to="/cart">
                                    Cart
                                </NavLink>
                            </Badge>
)
```

What I expect is when I click the increase and decrease button, the quantity should update the `cartTotal` in other components without refreshing the page. However, when I clicked on those buttons, I got stuck that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quantity')` and once I refresh the state was updated. How can I have the state updated without refresh and avoid the mounting value error?